# Removing untextured faces from UV mapping

Tags: texturing, uv

Newbie to Blender In blender 2.91.0 I am making simple buildings and covering with texture using uv-mapping. Many of the faces are internal and will never be seen and have no texture applied to them. (The textures with the red letters in the attached picture)

Is there some way to select and delete the unwanted faces from the UV map? and hopefully rearrange the UV map using Smart UV project function or something similar to use all remaining space.[Image of my layout]

Apologies if this has been covered elsewhere[image: My Layout showing unwanted uv map faces]

Comment: Reason to not remove unseen internal faces from the mesh itself?

Answer (score 3):

You can't really remove the useless faces from the UV map but for example you can select them in the 3D view, *Unwrap > Reset*, which will stack them, and put them out of the *UV Editor* grid:

[image]

Then select the rest of the mesh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>) and unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* option. Now the selected part occupy the whole grid, as expected (but it means that you'll need an image that will match the new unwrap):

[image]

If we select both the useful and useless part, as you see, the useless part keeps its location. You can put it over the second UV unwrap but it's more convenient to separate the 2 parts if you ever need to select one or the other. Note that the useless will inherit of the texture that will be underneath (an image texture is always infinitely repeated in the *UV Editor*) but you said that this part won't be seen so you don't have to care. If you want this part to be alpha 0% you need to put it over a part of your image that will be alpha 0%:

[image]